# Rotating Rigidbody controller

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

There is my script Rigidbody controller -

```
public float Speed = 5f;
public float JumpHeight = 2f;
public float GroundDistance = 0.2f;
public float DashDistance = 5f;
public LayerMask Ground;

private Rigidbody _body;
private Vector3 _inputs = Vector3.zero;
private bool _isGrounded = true;
private Transform _groundChecker;


void Start()
{
    _body = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    _groundChecker = transform.GetChild(0);
}

void Update()
{
    _isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(_groundChecker.position, GroundDistance, Ground, QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore);


    _inputs = Vector3.zero;
    _inputs.x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    _inputs.z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    if (_inputs != Vector3.zero)
        transform.forward = _inputs;

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && _isGrounded)
    {
        _body.AddForce(Vector3.up * Mathf.Sqrt(JumpHeight * -2f * Physics.gravity.y), ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    }
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Sprint"))
    {
        Vector3 dashVelocity = Vector3.Scale(transform.forward, DashDistance * new Vector3((Mathf.Log(1f / (Time.deltaTime * _body.drag + 1)) / -Time.deltaTime), 0, (Mathf.Log(1f / (Time.deltaTime * _body.drag + 1)) / -Time.deltaTime)));
        _body.AddForce(dashVelocity, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    }  
}


void FixedUpdate()
{
    _body.MovePosition(_body.position + _inputs * Speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
}
```

What the best way to make a turn on y in the direction of the camera ? That is,the player turns to the side where the mouse is turned? Is it in fixedUpdate or  update?

This is the camera script:

```
public float Smoothness = 0.3F;
public Vector2 Sensitivity = new Vector2(4, 4);
public Vector2 LimitX = new Vector2(-70, 80);

private Vector2 NewCoord;
public Vector2 CurrentCoord;
private Vector2 vel;
public GameManager GameMangerS;

public Transform Target;
public float TransformSpeed;

public Animator CameraAnimator;

void Update()
{
    NewCoord.x = Mathf.Clamp(NewCoord.x, LimitX.x, LimitX.y);
    NewCoord.x -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * Sensitivity.x;
    NewCoord.y += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * Sensitivity.y;
    CurrentCoord.x = Mathf.SmoothDamp(CurrentCoord.x, NewCoord.x, ref vel.x, Smoothness / 2);
    CurrentCoord.y = Mathf.SmoothDamp(CurrentCoord.y, NewCoord.y, ref vel.y, Smoothness / 2);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(CurrentCoord.x, CurrentCoord.y, 0);
}
```

And added this line to the controller script -

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    _body.MovePosition(_body.position + _inputs * Speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, MainCamera.CurrentCoord.y, 0);
}
```

When I'm standing the player normally rotates, but when I start to move, all rotations are reset and the player is not moving.

Comment: You move Physics in the `FixedUpdate` function. In this case, `_body` is a `Rigidbody` so it should be used in the `FixedUpdate` function.

Comment: How is it better to do it? How to rotate a player?

Comment: using transform.Rotate() or transform.LookAt()

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Simple Rotation can be achieved using transform.Rotate().

Example:

```
this.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, 30);
```

This example is gonna rotate the transform by 30° around the Vector that points upwards.

**LookAtMouse:**

To make your object turn towards the mouse, you need the [ScreenToWorldSpace](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html)() method from your camera. In order to convert the ScreenCoordinates into your WorldCoordinates.

Example:

**Please note:**

> 1. You have to set the camera instance! If you don't add that, you'll get a NullReferenceException.
> 2. This Snippets shall only show the steps needed to achieve the behavior you wish.
> 3. You will have to find out yourself how to integrate that lines of code into your code to make it work. Consider what Programmer told you in the comment when integrating that.

```
Vector3 mousePosition = Input.mousePosition; //get the screenSpaceMousePosition
Vector3 worldPosition = this.camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition); //convert it into worldSpacePosition
Vector3 calculatedDirection = worldPosition - transform.position; //calucate the looking direction
calculatedDirection.y = 0; 
Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(calculatedDirection);
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, Time.deltaTime);
```